# Why isn't this php login form working as expected?

Tags: php, session

The code commands in this script don't run and show up in the html page.

```
<script type="text/php">
<?php
    $_SESSION['userUID'] = "uidUsers";
    if(isset($_SESSION['userUID']))
    {
        echo '<form action="/loginsystemtut/includes/logout.inc.php" method="post">
            <button type="submit" name="logout-submit">Logout</button>
            </form>';
    } elseif(!isset($_SESSION['userUID'])) {
        echo '<form action="/loginsystemtut/includes/login.inc.php" method="post">
                <button type="submit" name="login-submit">Login</button>
            </form>';
    }
?>
</div>
</script>
```

I am trying to get login button to show when the user is logged in and the logout button to show when the user is logged out.

Comment: <script type="text/php"> ?

Answer (score 2):

Remove the script tags & replace your code with the example below.

```
<?php

$_SESSION['userUID'] = "uidUsers";

if (isset($_SESSION['userUID'])) :?>
    <form action="/loginsystemtut/includes/logout.inc.php" method="post">
        <button type="submit" name="logout-submit">Logout</button>
    </form>
<?php else : ?>
    <form action="/loginsystemtut/includes/login.inc.php" method="post">
        <button type="submit" name="login-submit"> Login</button>
    </form>
<?php endif ?>
```

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way to hide login when logged in and logout when logged out?